# How can I make this If Loop into a dictionary valid for Python

Tags: python, if-statement, switch-statement, combinations, boolean-logic

Am working on a fun little python project, and I am stuck trying to adapt my If loop into  Dictionary, but I am just not sure how to implement this function, as I need multiple conditions to be tested.

I have Six Booleans, (bool1-bool6) that can obviously be T or F, and
I need to test every possible combination of these booleans, so that I can tell my program where to draw the images.

There are 64 Possible combinations.

We can do this with 3 booleans to make it simple, There are 8 Possible combinations for 3 booleans.

If we imagine that 1=true and 0=false, then the possible combinations can be represented as such.

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

an if loop to represent this would be,

```
if (bool1==false and bool2==false and bool3==false)
      do stuff
elif (bool1==false and bool2==false and bool3==true)
     do stuff
elif (bool1==false and bool2==true and bool3==false)
     do stuff

and so on...
```

Please unless you can find a way to simplify this process, (understanding that I need to check ALL POSSIBLE combinations of booleans), there is no need to criticize my question. I am simply unsure of how to progress from here, and would greatly appreciate some help.

I have written out a 64 statement If Loop, and am currently working on that solution, though both myself and I'm sure my cpu would prefer a quicker method.

Comment: It kind of depends on the `do_stuff`. In the question you say you need to draw something?

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as an "if loop". I think you meant "if statement".

Comment: What exactly happens in these 64 cases? Is it a completely isolated piece of code for each condition or is it closely coupled to the boolean variables?

Comment: Thanks for the info stybi,

And I am aiming to write to a canvas.
There are Six Lines I need to write, Say,

Line1
Line2
Line3
etc,

but if line2 = 0, then I need to draw the pdf As,
Line1
Line3
etc

Comment: As a general rule. Do not compare Boolean values to `true` or `false`. They are true or false *themselves* already, so `if (bool1 == true and bool2 == false)` is superfluous. It's an antipattern. It wastes space, requires more typing and adds no value to the program. Use `if (bool1 and not bool2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a perfect example for using the bit representation of integers

You have your six boolean variables bool1 up to bool6.

Want you want is a bit represenation as the following example:

```
101101
```

Where the most left bit stands for bool6 and the most right for bool1.
So you get the order bool6, bool5, bool4, ..., bool1.

Now you assign a variable with the state, represented by those boolean variables:

```
state = bool6 << 5
state = state ^ (bool5 << 4)
state = state ^ (bool4 << 3)
state = state ^ (bool3 << 2)
state = state ^ (bool2 << 1)
state = state ^ (bool1)
```

you find an explaination for `<<` [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

What happend now is, you defined a new integer variable, represented by your different boolean values.

### Using the bit representation

Depending on your further `do_something` implementation, you define the method parameters like this:

```
cases = {
    0b000011 : "drawing parameter",
    0b001011 : "drawing parameter",
    0b111000 : "another drawing parameter",
}
```

Where, the dictionary keys are your bits from `000000` up to `111111`

Addionally, you can check whether each case has a defined parameter:

```
for n in range(1<<6):
    if not n in cases:
       raise LookupError('cases do not contain index %d' % n)
```

So, later on, you can use these bit representations like in the following.

```
for c in cases:
    if state == c: # if the checked case is equal to the state, then use the parameters
       parameters = cases[c]
       do_something(parameters)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @maik-s , This all looks absulutely perfect, and I cant wait to implement and post my updated code, But I am new, and slightly confused at the concept of bitvalues. Would you mind explaining to me what you did there? I mean how you get 3 and 11.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Did not see your answer when I posted mine.

Comment: @COLDSPEED no apologies necessary :)

Comment: Wait Nevermind @maik-s I get it now thank you so much. Genius!

Comment: Am I the only one who gets a bellyache when seeing a floating point function `pow` being used for integer bit shifting instead of the `<<` operator?

Comment: I would write the index numbers in the dict as `0b111000` instead of `56`, and would add a loop after the definition of `cases` which checks that there actually is a case for every number from `0` up to and including `((1<<6)-1)`: `for n in range(1<<6): if not n in cases: raise LookupError('cases do not contain index %d' % n)`

Comment: @Owen Redo please notice the updated bitwise `&` operator within the if statement

Comment: The binary representation of the number `64` is *not* `0b111111`. `64` is `0b1000000`. However, you are only dealing with the 64 numbers from `0b000000` (`0`) up to and including `0b111111` (`63`) here, not with the number `64` itself.

Comment: @maik-s What use is that `if bits & c:`? That conditional expression is always `True` except when `c` is `0`, so the only effect this has is *not* checking the `0` case from `cases`. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157739/discussion-between-maik-s-and-ndim).

Answer (score 0):

For 6 booleans, there are 2^6 combinations which directly correspond to the bits in the numbers from from `0` up to and including `2^6-1`. If you need to define special parameters to a single function call, you can solve this by having a list or dictionary of parameters, and then call that function with every parameter:

```
cases = {
    0b000000: ((arg1a, arg2y), {'key1': kwarg1, 'key2': kwarg2}),
    0b000001: ((arg1b, arg2x), {'key23': kwarg23, 'key7': kwarg7}),
    # ...
    0b111111: ((arg1a, arg2z), {'key4': kwarg4, 'key2': kwarg2}),
}

for n, (args, kwargs) in cases.items():
    print("Test case {:d} ({:#08b}):".format(n,n))
    test_fun(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you do not need keyword arguments, you can simplify that easily.

If you need to do more specific stuff, you can have lambdas in the dictionary instead of parameter sets:

```
cases = {
    0b000000: lambda: test_fun(1,2, foo='bar'),
    0b000001: lambda: test_fun(3,2, moo='bar'),
    # ...
    0b111111: lambda: test_fun(8,3, foo='bar'),
    }

for n, fun in cases.items():
    print("Test case {:d} ({:#08b}):".format(n,n))
    fun()
```

You could also turn those dictionaries into lists and the dict indexes into comments:

```
cases = [
    # 0b000000
    ((arg1a, arg2y), {'key1': kwarg1, 'key2': kwarg2}),
    # 0b000001
    ((arg1b, arg2x), {'key23': kwarg23, 'key7': kwarg7}),
    # ...
    # 0b111111
    ((arg1a, arg2z), {'key4': kwarg4, 'key2': kwarg2}),
]

for n, (args, kwargs) in enumerate(cases):
    print("Test case {:d} ({:#08b}):".format(n,n))
    test_fun(*args, **kwargs)
```

In all cases, I would make sure to place a consistency check directly after the definition of `cases`, such as

```
# for the `cases` dictionary
for n in range(1<<6):
    if not n in cases:
        raise LookupError("dict variable cases does not contain %d" % n)

# for the `cases` list
assert(len(cases) == (1<<6))
```

If you can easily machine derive the parameter sets from the index number, you can avoid defining that complete list or dict of test cases and just calculate the parameter values on the fly:

```
for n in range(1<<6):
    param1 = 23
    if (n & (1<<0)):
        param1 = 42
    # ...
    param6 = bool(n & (1<<5))

    # ...
    test_fun(param1, ..., param6)
```

Or you can put the parameter generating logic into a generator function, optionally replacing the tuple expression in the yield statement with a (possibly `reversed()`) `list`.

```
def all_bool_tuples_from_bits(n):
    for k in range(1<<n):
        yield (bool(k&(1<<i)) for i in range(n))

print("Run test_fun with the arguments")
for args in all_bool_tuples_from_bits(6):
    test_fun(*args)

print("Run test_fun with the arguments in explicit variables")
for p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 in all_bool_tuples_from_bits(6):
    test_fun(p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)

print("Run test_fun with the arguments while numbering the test cases")
for n, args in enumerate(all_bool_tuples_from_bits(6)):
    print("Test case {:d} ({:#08b}):".format(n,n))
    test_fun(*args)
```

I hope this gives you a few ideas to work with.

Regarding CPU usage, I would not worry at all for just 64 different test cases which each generate a PDF file which is certain to be much more CPU intensive than iterating over 64 test cases can ever be.

The real worry is that you might forget to list one case in that huge `if elif elif elif` construct and not notice this yourself. So I would want to use code to have the computer make sure every combination is indeed examined. For just 6 boolean parameters, I would use the generator.

Answer (score 0):

The int-to-binary approach is clever but doesn't generalize. There is an easier way that also generalizes to data types other than Boolean:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.product((0, 1,), repeat=3):
    ... stuff ...
```

This will return tuples like `(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1) ... (1, 1, 1)`.

You can change the unnamed first parameter to any iterable - `xrange()`, set, array etc. - and the `repeat` parameter to the desired length. Works for any data type.